# Spark scala creating dataFrame from rdd using Row and Schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, row, rdd

I am trying to create a dataframe from RDD in order to be able to write to a json with following format
A sample json is as shown below(expected output)

"1234":[
    {
        loc:'abc',
        cost1:1.234,
        cost2:2.3445
    },
    {
       loc:'www',
        cost1:1.534,
        cost2:6.3445 
    }
]

I am able to generate the json with cost1 and cost2 in String format. But I want cost1 and cost2 to be double. 
I am getting error while creating data frame from rdd using schema defined. 
Somehow the data is being considered as String instead of double.
Can someone help me to get this right?
Below is my scala code of my sample implementation

```
object csv2json {
  def f[T](v: T) = v match {
  case _: Int    => "Int"
  case _: String => "String"
  case _: Float => "Float"
  case _: Double => "Double"
  case _:BigDecimal => "BigDecimal"
  case _         => "Unknown"
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val input_df = Seq(("12345", "111","1.34","2.34"),("123456", "112","1.343","2.344"),("1234", "113","1.353","2.354"),("1231", "114","5.343","6.344")).toDF("item_id","loc","cost1","cost2")
    input_df.show()  
    val inputRDD =  input_df.rdd.map(data => {

        val  nodeObj  = scala.collection.immutable.Map("nodeId" -> data(1).toString()
        ,"soc" -> data(2).toString().toDouble
        ,"mdc" -> data(3).toString().toDouble)
        (data(0).toString(),nodeObj)
      })

      val inputRDDAgg = inputRDD.aggregateByKey(scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Any])((nodeAAggreg,costValue) => nodeAAggreg += costValue , (nodeAAggreg,costValue) => nodeAAggreg ++ costValue)

      val inputRDDAggRow = inputRDDAgg.map(data => {
        println(data._1 + "and------ " + f(data._1))
        println(data._2 + "and------ " + f(data._2))

        val  skuObj  = Row(
         data._1,
         data._2)
        skuObj
      }
      )

      val innerSchema =  ArrayType(MapType(StringType, DoubleType, true))
      val schema:StructType = StructType(Seq(StructField(name="skuId", dataType=StringType),StructField(name="nodes", innerSchema)))
      val finalJsonDF = spark.createDataFrame(inputRDDAggRow, schema)
      finalJsonDF.show()
  }
}
```

Below is the exception stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, skuId), StringType), true, false) AS skuId#32
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else mapobjects(MapObjects_loopValue0, MapObjects_loopIsNull0, ObjectType(class java.lang.Object), if (isnull(validateexternaltype(lambdavariable(MapObjects_loopValue0, MapObjects_loopIsNull0, ObjectType(class java.lang.Object), true), MapType(StringType,DoubleType,true)))) null else newInstance(class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.ArrayBasedMapData), validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, nodes), ArrayType(MapType(StringType,DoubleType,true),true)), None) AS nodes#33
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:589)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:589)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to stay with dataset or dataframe by using inbult functions as they are optimized version of rdds.

So you can do the following to achieve your requirement

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val finalJsonDF = input_df
  .groupBy("item_id")
  .agg(
    collect_list(
      struct(col("loc"), col("cost1").cast("double"), col("cost2").cast("double")))
      .as("jsonData"))
```

where `collect_list` and `struct` are inbuilt functions

which should give you

```
+-------+-------------------+
|item_id|jsonData           |
+-------+-------------------+
|123456 |[[112,1.343,2.344]]|
|1234   |[[113,1.353,2.354]]|
|1231   |[[114,5.343,6.344]]|
|12345  |[[111,1.34,2.34]]  |
+-------+-------------------+
```

and saving the jsonData to json file as your requirement

```
finalJsonDF.coalesce(1).write.json("path to output file")
```

should give you

```
{"item_id":"123456","jsonData":[{"loc":"112","col2":1.343,"col3":2.344}]}
{"item_id":"1234","jsonData":[{"loc":"113","col2":1.353,"col3":2.354}]}
{"item_id":"1231","jsonData":[{"loc":"114","col2":5.343,"col3":6.344}]}
{"item_id":"12345","jsonData":[{"loc":"111","col2":1.34,"col3":2.34}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see schema mismatch in your code. I made simple fix as an workaround

I converted `data(1).toString`  to `data(1).toString.toDouble`. In your `ArrayType(MapType(StringType, DoubleType, true))`, you have mentioned all the values are `Double`  where as one of your value is `String`. I believe that is the issue.

```
val inputRDD =  input_df.rdd.map(data => {

      val  nodeObj  = scala.collection.immutable.Map("nodeId" -> data(1).toString.toDouble
        ,"soc" -> data(2).toString().toDouble
        ,"mdc" -> data(3).toString().toDouble)
      (data(0).toString(),nodeObj)
    })
```

**Output**

```
+------+--------------------------------------------------+
|skuId |nodes                                             |
+------+--------------------------------------------------+
|1231  |[Map(nodeId -> 114.0, soc -> 5.343, mdc -> 6.344)]|
|12345 |[Map(nodeId -> 111.0, soc -> 1.34, mdc -> 2.34)]  |
|123456|[Map(nodeId -> 112.0, soc -> 1.343, mdc -> 2.344)]|
|1234  |[Map(nodeId -> 113.0, soc -> 1.353, mdc -> 2.354)]|
+------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: With this change, nodeID is changed to double. But in my json, I want nodeId to be String and only cost must be double. Hence in schema I have gived StringType and DoubleType. If I want nodeId to be string, can you please suggest any changes to schema definition?